# iPhone App Icon Submission

Tags: iphone, icons, submission

I have submitted my iPhone app for approval and uploaded my icon.

Now, I get the feeling the corners on my icon aren't the right shape. I noticed this when uploading my app as in iTunes Connect it displays my icon with a pre-made shadow behind it and makes it look like my corners come in to tightly.

See the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z48H.png). Zoom in on it to get a better look.

You see the corner of my icon, then the shadow further out, below that. Anyone experienced this before? Will it look funny if I leave it? Black out that space? Or will it just stay transparent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes Connect has had this issue for sometime but it does not affect the main product, for piece of mind you can check the correct icon inside your uploaded versions detail page, it should show the 'Large App Icon' correctly